# How to Delete a Key Dictionary

Tags: swift

We have a array of Dictionary.
In the Dictionary we have a Key called line_of_action.
How to remove the Key from the dictionary.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quite unusual but valid syntax in Swift is setting the value to `nil` with subscripting.

```
fruits["apple"] = nil
```

Comment: I actually *prefer* this syntax over `removeValueForKey`, as (for me) it's much clearer that the entire "key/value" entry is removed and not just the "value".

Answer (score 0):

```
    var myDict = ["foo":"bar"]
    myDict.removeValueForKey("foo")
```

Am I missing something to your question ?

Comment: I know it's an old post, but in case anybody stumble upon this thread..Bear in mind that remove method takes O(n) complexity.

Answer (score 0):

To remove into a Dictionary using the **Key** you could either use `removeValueForKey` or `removeAtIndex`

Example let say we have an Dictionary called **my**

```
var my = [String:String]()
my = ["name":"James","age":"75","location":"StackOverflow"]
```

And I want to remove the Value for the **location  <---- Key**

first method:

```
my.removeValueForKey("location")
```

Second method:

```
my.removeAtIndex(my.indexForKey("location")!)
```

Hope that helps you and please post the code you have tried when you are asking a question. `:)`